# Change product options templates in layout XML (in module)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to change product options templates :

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
</block>
```

In my module, I try several methods:

```
<referenceBlock name="text" template="Vendor_Module::path/to/newfile.phtml" />
```

--

```
<referenceBlock name="text">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::path/to/newfile.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

--

```
<referenceBlock name="text">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::path/to/newfile.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

*This one is really weird*

To check, i try with name = "copyright", and it works...

How can I do it with product options templates ?

Note : The changes that will be made in the templates are not for appearance.

Excuse my english

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your extension **your_extension/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.options" remove="true" />

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="yourcustomname.product.info.options" as="yourcustomname.packaging_product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="Your_Extension::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

And copy

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/text.phtml**

to

**your_extension/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/text.phtml**

You make the modifications in the `text.phtml` of your extension.

This solution could cause problems if there is another extension that modifies the block `product.info.options`